# Image exceeding div size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a header div as follows:

```
<div class="header">        
    <div class="row">           
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-md-2">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="logo.png"/>                
        </div>          
    </div>    
</div>
```

Here is the header class:

```
.header {
    background-color: #5DBCD2;
    height: 10%;
}
```

Even though the div's max height is restricted to 10%, the image exceeds this.

Can someone please help

Answer (score 10):

Add the following to your CSS so that you can have the image contained within the div nicely as it scales down.

```
.header img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

You can also add `overflow: hidden;` to the header element but that will cut it off rather than scale it, but it is another potential option.

Comment: this didnt change anything

Comment: Did you add the code exactly as above? I missed the dot from the class selector. Try it again.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it will be to any help, but try to add a *max-height* to the image in CSS.

EDIT
You could add this in the CSS (so that the image has 10% of the width of the parent):

`.img-responsive {
   width: 10%;
}`

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code with an image of 2000 x 1522 pixel dimensions.

Worked fine.

Few things you can do:

> 1) Debug your page using Developer tools in the browser.
>
> 2) Check if your css file path is correct.
>
> 3) Check for any errors in console part of the developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

In your above code bootstrap before declaring *row* you must first declare *container* you should have something like this below

```
<div class="header">
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 col-md-2"> 
        <img class="img-responsive" src="logo.png"/> 
      </div> 
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Probably this should work